# Is there way to extract data audio from an mp3 file picked by an user on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio-processing

My project involves working with audio files to process the audio signal they contain to compare them to other files. The main problem I've been facing for many hours now is that I don't know how or what libraries to use **to extract the audio signal data** from an audio file (mp3 or other types) into an float array for example. My only issue lies in the data extraction of an audio file chosen by the user of my application.

Idealy, this float array would then contain at the `n` index the pressure measured of the microphone that recorded the audio track at the time `t=n*dt` where `dt` is a fixed constant. (`dt` is in this case the sample time that will be defined prior to the data extraction of the audio file)

I don't know how mp3 files and other types are encoded,
I tried to use the **TarsosDSP** library without any success,
I am using **Android Studio** and the **java**.

Am I missing permissions  ?

As stated before, I tried to use the **TarsosDSP** library :
I successfully imported the library by puting the `.jar` file in the `/libs` folder and then adding it in the project with `File>Project Structure>Dependencies>(+) (add icon)` then specifying the location of the `TarsosDSP` library. (which is `libs/TarsosDSP-Android-latest.jar`)

Once that out of the way, here's my code requesting the user to choose one file :

```java
public void requestFileSeeking(View view){
        Snackbar.make(view,"Requested file choosing", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        myFileIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        myFileIntent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(myFileIntent, 10);
    }
```

Btw, the `startActivityForResult()` function is deprecated, so if you got a better way to do this, I'm all ears but it's not the main issue.

What is problematic is the following code :

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_SONG_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            // Create an AudioDispatcher instance and attach a FileProcessor to it

            // This line causes the error when I choose a file
            AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromPipe(uri.getPath(), 44100, 4096, 0);

            Toast.makeText(this, uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new AudioProcessor() {

                @Override
                public boolean process(AudioEvent audioEvent) {
                    // Process audio data here
                    float[] audioBuffer = audioEvent.getFloatBuffer().clone();
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void processingFinished() {
                    // Final processing here
                }
            });

            dispatcher.run();
        }
    }
```

So here, looks like everything's good because IntellJ suggests to import all the classes from the `TarsosDSP` without any error.

The issue is when I try to select a file on the emulator when running the application. The moment `onActivityResult()` is called, there is this fatal error coming up :

```java
E/PipeDecoder: Could not find an ffmpeg binary for your Android system. Did you forget calling: 'new AndroidFFMPEGLocator(this);' ?
E/PipeDecoder: Tried to unpack a statically compiled ffmpeg binary for your architecture to: /data/user/0/com.example.youknowthatsong/cache/ffmpeg
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.youknowthatsong, PID: 32739
    java.lang.Error: Decoding via a pipe will not work: Could not find an ffmpeg binary for your system
        at be.tarsos.dsp.io.PipeDecoder.<init>(Unknown Source:350)
        at be.tarsos.dsp.io.PipedAudioStream.<clinit>(Unknown Source:2)
        at be.tarsos.dsp.io.android.AudioDispatcherFactory.fromPipe(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.youknowthatsong.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:198)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8939)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5474)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5520)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:138)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2401)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8128)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:946)
```

Me and my team did a lot of research to try and find to install this `ffmpeg binary` but to no avail, it either did the same error even when we tried to install it, or it gave another similar error...

I would be really delighted if someone already went through this and could guide us !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `uri.getPath()` Does not give you a file system path and cannot be used to read a file. Have a look at uri.toString() to see the content scheme. Use full uri to read the file.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but thought I did what you said and did make some research, I couldn't find the way to extract the audio data from the file :(

Comment: Well what was the problem?

Comment: I still have the same issue : "Could not find an ffmpeg binary for your Android system."